# Preview of selected image in the upload dialog before actually uploading

Tags: feature-request, chat

A few minutes ago I was trying to upload an image to the chat. By mistake, I chose `asdasdgsdfg.png` instead of `asdasdgsdff.png` and ended up uploading something *totally* different. I know I should be sensibly naming my files, but it would be nice to have a preivew of the selected image just before you click "Upload".

I think this is possible using the File API. Actually, [MDN has an example of doing just that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images).

[image]

Comment: Your picture is missing something red, vaguely circular, and hand-drawn.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Fixed

Comment: Excellent! Now we can all tell what you are referring to! ;)

Comment: I presume there is no way to delete anything once it's been uploaded, yes? If that's the case then I totally agree. I don't need *those* photos accidentally making their way around the web (again).

Comment: @JonW You can delete it but it's pretty annoying. This is a quick fix that can only do good.

Comment: I remember there being a preview dialog. Perhaps it's because I always drag the image file directly to the upload box? Don't have a computer to check :(

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary workaround until such feature will be available, you can follow one of those methods in a Chrome browser to get a preview.

First click the image upload icon to open the dialog.

#### Method A

Drag the picture file from Windows Explorer into the image upload dialog.

#### Method B

1. Click the Browse button in the image upload dialog.
2. Right click the image file you want to add and choose to Open it with some image editor of your choice.
3. In the image editor, choose Copy. (copy the image data to clipboard, you might need to click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> first to select it)
4. Cancel the file selection to go back to the image upload.
5. Click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the image from clipboard. (this step working only in Chrome)

With either of those methods, you will now get a nice dandy preview allowing you to insta-upload:

> [image]

Comment: I'm aware of that feature while writing answers/questions. However, it's not working in the chat (at least not in Chrome)

Comment: @Adnan oh, didn't know that. So asking to integrate this feature into the chat image upload might have faster response from the dev team. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Even faster method is Click image upload icon -> From your explorer drag and drop an image in the uploader. It will show you the preview. But it too doesn't work in the chat.

Comment: Thanks @hims056, added this to the answer. :)